# Add optional weight to override default sorting of items in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a collection (`work`) of papers in a Jekyll website. These items have a publication date (`pub_date`), so there is no problem sorting them by reverse chronological order with something like

```
{% assign work_sorted = site.work | sort: 'pub_date' | reverse %}
```

However, I want to be able to *optionally* specify a `order` integer to override the default order, so that if an item has the `order` variable, it is sorted by that first. Then all items without `order` should follow, sorted by reversed `pub_date`.

I've tried using `group_by`, but I can't leave items with empty `order` last. I've also thought about adding a default value to `order` if empty (something like 999), but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy if instead of order (lowest number show first), you use priority (highest number show first). Meaning that if you have 5 pieces of `work` as follows:

```
---
title: work-a
pub_date: 18-07-10
---

---
title: work-b
pub_date: 18-07-11
---

---
title: work-c
pub_date: 18-07-12
---

---
title: work-d
pub_date: 18-07-13
---

---
title: work-e
pub_date: 18-07-14
---
```

Your current code will output the items in this order:

```
work-e
work-d
work-c
work-b
work-a
```

Let's say you want, `work-c` to be shown first and `work-a` second, whilst the rest just in reverse chronological order. Add a `priority` property to the front matter of `work-c` and `work-a` only:

```
---
title: work-a
pub_date: 18-07-10
priority: 2
---

---
title: work-b
pub_date: 18-07-11
---

---
title: work-c
pub_date: 18-07-12
priority: 1
---

---
title: work-d
pub_date: 18-07-13
---

---
title: work-e
pub_date: 18-07-14
---
```

The following code will give you the required result:

```
{% assign sorted = site.work| sort: 'pub_date' | reverse %}

{% assign ordered = sorted | sort: 'priority' | reverse %}

{% for item in ordered %}
<p>{{ item.title }} - {{ item.pub_date }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I've tested the above but do let me know if you have issues. You can still use the sort order (small first) but you will need to add a bunch of conditions and create arrays as strings on the fly so maybe this one is just better :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a default value to collection :

**_config.yml**

```
collections:
  work:
    output: true

defaults:
  - scope:
      type: work
    values:
      order: 999
```

Now, this filters chaining does the trick :

```
{% assign work_sorted = site.work | sort: 'pub_date' | reverse | sort: 'order' %}
```